# setContentView throws ERROR NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Im new to Java in many ways and for the life of me can't figure out why my 'imageactivity' layout can't be found at runtime when its found at compile time.  The file is located at "penguinplugin/rez/layout/imageactivity.xml"... is there something I need to set in Eclipse or my manifest for it to be found?

**NOTE: If I extract my built .jar file, it does not contain the "R$layout.class".  This is a library BTW, not excitable...**

My layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageactivityID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.86" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Take Picture!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity:

```
import com.penguin.penguinplugin.R;
public class PhotoPickerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.imageactivity);
    }
}
```

The exception thrown:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.penguin.penguinplugin.R$layout
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285):    at penguinplugin.PhotoPickerActivity.onCreate(PhotoPickerActivity.java:47)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1617)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1669)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:937)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3692)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1285):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Edit: So I think the reason it may not be working is because Eclipse doesn't built the resources into a library object(if so, hand palm)... only an exe.  But because this is for a unity plugin, I just programmatically created the simple view I needed without loading any resources.  So my problem is solved for this.**

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a single parent object to your layout file

something like this should do:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".YourActivity" >

    <SurfaceView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.86" />

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Take Picture!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sry updated my XML file, didn't realize the whole code block was not showing up in my post correctly.  So from looking at your post, it looks like i'm missing a 'context'?? Could that be my issue?  And should I remove the XML header tag?